# Java - When there is no user input prevent an error message - Homework

Tags: java

The program is supposed to take a string input by the user and return it reversed. (ex "Hello" is input "olleH" is the output.) You do this by running the program like `java ReverseCL2 Hello` However, when no string is input with it, it prints an `ArrayOutOfIndexException`. I need it to instead print out what the user is supposed to do (Please input a string when running the code.) I have tried what is below and also `if (args[0].equals(null))`. Thanks in advance for any help :)

```
public class ReverseCL2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = args[0];
        String rev = "";
        if (args[0].isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Input a string to be reversed");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) 
            {
                rev = s.charAt(i) + rev;
            }
            System.out.println(rev);
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for `args.length` being zero first, i.e.

```
if(args.length == 0 || args[0].isEmpty())
{
    // <Handle special case however you like>
}
```

The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` you get is a result of trying to access `args[0]` when `args` has size `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ReverseCL2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        if(args.length == 0 || args[0].isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Input a string to be reversed");
            return;
        }

        String s = args[0];
        String rev = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        {
            rev = s.charAt(i) + rev;
        }

        System.out.println(rev);

    } 
}
```

Comment: +1: Fair point - you (i.e. the OP) still need to check for it then being empty as well.

Comment: `if(args.length == 0 || args[0].isEmpty())` checks for `empty array` and `empty value`... this code is absolutely correct. (and this is really a basic problem)

Comment: Yes, I know - I was observing that I answered the question too quickly and just showed how to avoid the exception whilst stupidly forgetting the second part of the condition. Hence the upvote I gave you, and the fact that I then corrected myself :)

Answer (score 0):

put `!` for checking the parameterized array value

```
if (!args[0].isEmpty() && args.length==0)
```

See above line in your code.

```
    public class ReverseCL2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = args[0];
        String rev = "";
        if (!args[0].isEmpty() && args.length==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Input a string to be reversed");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) 
            {
                rev = s.charAt(i) + rev;
            }
            System.out.println(rev);
        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
It simple arg0 is array so before get data from That check Array size 


if(args.length == 0)
{
    // <Show message to user >
}else{

// <write here Working code >

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answers a more simpler code(reading vise) would be

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    switch (args.length) {

        case 0 : System.out.println("Input a string to be reversed");
            break;
        default:    //your logic

    }
}
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't do an empty check on `args[0]` when `args.length != 0`.

Comment: That logic would come in the default case(Non zero arguments). You can always check for empty or null before processing the data.